# Scss setting value of variable in selector causes it to change even if no element with given selector is available

Tags: html, css, sass

SCSS File

```
$dark-theme: false!default;
$primary-dark: blue;

[dark-mode='dark'] {
  background:gray!important;
  $dark-theme: true!global;
}

[dark-mode='light'] {
  background:yellow!important;
  $dark-theme: false!global;
}

@if $dark-theme==true{
  $primary-dark: black!global;
} @else{
  $primary-dark: blue!global;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body dark-mode="dark">
</body>
</html>
```

The above code always sets $dark-theme value given in `[dark-mode='light']` while background is set correctly

Comment: Why you expecting sass performance once it is compiled that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood how SASS works. SASS variables are used only during compilation, hence once the code is compiled, they no longer exist.

The selectors `[dark-mode='light']` and `[dark-mode='dark']` are both always compiled regardless of whether there is an element with the value `dark` or `light` in your DOM. Since the `light` properties are the last set in the code, `$dark-theme` will always be `false` when it goes to your `@if` and so `$primary-dark` will always have the value `blue`.

If you want to keep this approach, you can take a look at [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead. [Here is a nice article about this](https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/css-custom-properties-vs-sass-variables#color-themes).

Comment: Realized that later. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @ManishSharma If my answer helped you please consider accepting it by clicking on the grey tick next to it. :)